# Can't find class in HTML

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm learning web crawling and I stumbled upon a problem, which is HTML related(I guess)

So i found this freelance [project](https://www.freelancer.com/projects/php-software-architecture/data-extraction-from-two-links/) as learning material, and I have to find 'shop name', 'address' and so on... of these 24 pawnbrokers.

My problem is that I can't locate all the shops in HTML:

```
content = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"list list-unstyled"})
```

.......

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.thenpa.com/Find-A-Pawnbroker.aspx'
#opening up the connection, grabbing the page
uClient = urlopen(my_url)
#offloads the content
page_html = uClient.read()

uClient.close()
#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
#grabs each pawnbroker
content = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"list list-unstyled"})
```

makes sense that it should be

```
<div class=fab-loc-list"> == $0
```

[Screenshot of HTML element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0lEY.png)

but its not

Comment: you div doesn't have those classes so why would you expect it to find that div?

Comment: @Pete where should i look for it then?

Comment: The element with those classes is a `ul`, not a `div`.

Comment: The _real_ problem you are dealing with here, is that in the initial HTML of the document there is only `<ul class="list list-unstyled"></ul>` - so the actual content gets loaded only later on via client-side JavaScript. Your research into how to properly handle such cases can start f.e. here, https://www.google.com/search?q=scrape%20page%20contents%20added%20via%20javascript

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time

chrome_path = "/home/intellus/python_code/chromedriver"
display = Display(visible=1, size=(2600,720))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
my_url = 'https://www.thenpa.com/Find-A-Pawnbroker.aspx'

driver.get(my_url)
time.sleep(10)

page_html = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
content = page_soup.find("ul", {"class":"list list-unstyled"}).findAll("li")

print(len(content))
```